# Enable/Disable Scrolling in iPhone/iPad’s BUT enable the website scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll

Please I am trying to figure our a way to Disable Scrolling in iPhone/iPad’s Safari Browser, but keep the website scrollable.

I have tried to add this function:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

and it works perfectly fine, the only problem tho, that it also disables scrolling within the website! please help. Thanks.

Live example for the website: http://www.webdesignstudents.co.uk/students/loai_shehadeh/LOAI%20Design%20Studio%20Final/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if the device is mobile using a function like this

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
var check = false;
(function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
return check; }
```

This code scans the User Agent to check if it appears to be a mobile device. Using this, you can do something like

```
if (window.mobilecheck())
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

So that code only adds the scroll blocker if it is a mobile device!

Comment: Thank you, so I have applied it, and the following happened:

The website content is scrollable only up and down, and it solved part of the website dragging in the browser, as it can be dragged up and down only but not left and right...

Comment: That code right there alone should not affect dragging on a computer; try removing the code and see what happens to your dragging. Also, a question about how to prevent dragging should be a new question, this one is mainly for how to do it on a mobile browser given certain code to prevent dragging ;)

Comment: It does mate, it won't work on a computer even here is the link: http://www.webdesignstudents.co.uk/students/loai_shehadeh/LOAI%20Design%20Studio%20Final/index.html

all what I wanted to do is to stop the whole website box from being allowed to be dragged around the browser app space, but without disabling dragging and scrolling inside the website, do you know what i mean? thanks lot of ur time!

Comment: @Leo There doesn't appear to be any content to the right, which is why you can't scroll left/right. Mine scrolls up and down fine, and that seems to be all it needs

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. No js required

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        ... your html here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```